# Stored procedure left join top record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have company table contains `id, name` and I have contact table contains `company id, firstname, contacttype` (type = 40 (admin), type= 41 (user))

I have a query that creates a temp table that would have a row of company name, firstname (Admin), firstname (user) some records could have firstname (admin) some could have firstname (user) and some could have both.

```
DECLARE @tempreport TABLE 
(
   cName varchar(50), 
   cFirstAdmin varchar(50), 
   cFirstUser varchar(50)      
)

insert into @tempreport (cName, cFirstAdmin, cFirstUser)

SELECT
    company.name
    ,[admin].firstname AS FirstAdmin
    ,[user].firstname AS FirstUser
FROM company
LEFT JOIN contact [admin] ON [admin].companyid = company.id AND [admin].type = 40
LEFT JOIN contact [user] ON [user].companyid = company.id AND [user].type = 41
```

This works.

Question: in the `contact` table it is possible that it can have multiple contacts for example, company id (1), firstname (bob), type (40), company id (1), firstname (mike), type (40)

Currently it pulls both records, how do I modify so it pulls just the top record if more then one found?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use subqueries:

```
select company.name,
    (select top 1 firstname from contact 
     where contact.companyid = company.companyid 
     and contact.type = 40) as FirstAdmin,
    (select top 1 firstname from contact 
     where contact.companyid = company.companyid 
     and contact.type = 41) as FirstUser
from company
```

You can add more criteria or ordering to subqueries to select the user you want.

---

UPDATE:

As requested, here is a more complex version to get more columns for each user type. It uses left joins and `ROW_NUMBER()` to get only one row. I used ordering by `NEWID()` to make it random but you can order by anything you like.

```
select company.name, 
  contactadmin.firstname AdminFirstName, contactadmin.lastname AdminLastName,
  contactuser.firstname UserFirstName, contactuser.lastname UserLastName
from company
left join (select row_number() over (order by newid()) as rownumber, companyid, firstname, lastname from contact 
     where type = 40) contactadmin
     on contactadmin.companyid = company.companyid
     and contactadmin.rownumber = 1
left join (select row_number() over (order by newid()) as rownumber, companyid, firstname, lastname from contact 
     where type = 41) contactuser
     on contactuser.companyid = company.companyid
     and contactuser.rownumber = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb7da/19)

Comment: Which record do you want it to pull - using your example? Bob or Mike?

Comment: THe asker hasn't specified that and you can add `ORDER BY` to subqueries to decide that.

Comment: want top 1, first one it finds or I can I also use order by, this works, but I have 5 fields, e.g (firstname, lastname,email..etc) for type 40 and for type 41 so I need to create 10 subqueries? or is there another way? thanks

Comment: basically I want it to pull all the fields from the same record/row, so it doesnt pull top firstname from one record and lastname from a different record/row,